# Node crypto aes256-cbc 0x0 padding example

Tags: node.js, cryptography, aes, padding

From node cryptos [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_cipher_setautopadding_auto_padding_true):

> "You can disable automatic padding of the input data to block size. If auto_padding is false, the length of the entire input data must be a multiple of the cipher's block size or final will fail. Useful for non-standard padding, e.g. using 0x0 instead of PKCS padding. You must call this before cipher.final."

Which is all nice, however, i wasn't able to find a proper example anywhere:

Here are my thoughts on the manner:

```
function pad(str) {
  if((str.length*8)%256 != 0) {
    str+= "0";
    pad(str);
  } 
}

var str = "blah_blah_blah_blah_ asdf";
if(byteLength < 256) {
  for(i=byteLength;i<256;i+=8) {
    str += "0";
  }
} else if(byteLength > 256) {
  pad(str);
}
```

Now this is obviously not ideal since the cipher.final() method should remove the padding,
however it won't, also, i should probably pad it with hexes rather than chars.

Also, the modulus function fails on strings greater than 256 *shrug*

What's the proper way to use custom padding(0x0) with node crypto?

Comment: Why do you need to use zero padding? For interoperability with a legacy system that cannot be changed?

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid that we're trying to get in sync with multiple platforms all calling their own padding algorithms. I'm fine with decrypting the data regardless of the padding, however at certain points - i'd like to encrypt it to the same string I've originally received and different padding = different string eventually

Comment: If you can modify the other platforms, you should probably use PKCS#7 padding everywhere, since that's the standard. Zero padding is ambiguous – what if the plaintext ends in zeroes?

Comment: My plain text at the current tie will be base64 encoded and at this level, will be regarded as utf8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, after a little bit of tinkering, i got the whole thing working.

Here's my code for those who might find it useful:

## Updated for 2019 / node 10.15.0

#### node crypto will handle padding for you.

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
let key = crypto.randomBytes(32);

function encrypt(str) {
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
    let crypt = cipher.update(str, 'utf8', 'base64');
    crypt += cipher.final("base64");
    return crypt;
}

function decrypt(str) {
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
    let decrypt = decipher.update(str, 'base64', 'utf8');
    decrypt += decipher.final();
    return decrypt;
}

const enc = encrypt("dude5");
const dec = decrypt(enc);

console.log(enc, dec);
```

Comment: This is risky padding. During unpad, one can remove a legible 0x0. what do you think?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a newer and safer example. TL;DR - the module will take care of both padding and unpadding for you.